# Help with countifs formula

Tags: google-sheets

I need help with a countifs formula. I need to know how many candidate each of my sourceur (column A) has contacted on a specific date (column I)  [image]

Comment: If you want help with your formula, [edit] your question to include it and any details about what is and is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this `query()` formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=query(Sheet1!A1:I, "select I, count(I) where I is not null group by I pivot A", 1)
```

See [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343).